# Scrapy spider returns different values compared to browser console xpath result

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

xpath:

```
//ol[@class="breadcrumb container"]/li[not(contains(@class,"first")) and not(contains(@class,"last"))]/a/span/text()
```

HTML:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb container">
    <li class="first"><a href="http://example.com/index.php?route=common/home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/books"><span>Books</span></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="http://example.com/books?product_id=193" class="last"><span>My Vision : Challenges in the Race for Excellence - Mohammed Bin Rashid Al Maktoum</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

Python code:

```
categories = ['NO DATA', 'NO DATA', 'NO DATA', 'NO DATA', 'NO DATA', 'NO DATA']
catIndex = 0
for cat in sel.xpath('//ol[@class="breadcrumb container"]/li[not(contains(@class,"first")) and not(contains(@class,"last"))]/a/span/text()').extract():
            categories[catIndex] = cat
            catIndex += 1
```

Wanted result is "Books" and when I check it on Firebug console with xpath it returns correct result but when I run spider it returns whole 3 Li elements not excluding class="first" and class="last"

I tried command Scrapy View http://example.com to see page how spider sees it but everything looks same and xpath returns correct result

[image: Scrapy view]

When I tried using xpath in Scrapy Shell it returns incorrect result of all 3 Li elements

[image: Scrapy Shell]

What might be the problem?

Comment: actually if u check the page source from ur browser it will show u that the first and last li element have no class attributes so ultimately u will get all three elements in results. That is the problem.

Comment: u need to make changes in ur xpath to get the correct output that u want.

Comment: You are right <li> doesn't have Class attribute

Answer (score 0):

Opened Scrapy View http://example.com output in Internet Explorer and saw that Li elements doesn't have Class attribute in there.

It apears that Scrapy View Command opened in Chrome or Firefox doesn't show REALL code which spider sees.